How to resize a button foreground to fit its view in a SwiftUI form
I have a page in swift like below.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SomeViewName: View {

   @State private var languages = [String]()

   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
               Section(header: Text("Some Section")) {
                    ForEach(0..<allergies.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        TextField("Please enter your language", text: $languages[index])
                    }
                    if language.count < 5 {
                        Button(action: {
                            language.append("")
                        }) {
                            Text("Click to add a language")
                        }
                    }
                }

                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(height: 50)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    Button(action: {
                        saveDetails()
                    }) {
                        Text("Save your details")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // Remove the default button style
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) // Remove default padding
            }
            .navigationTitle("Your Known Languages")
            
        }
    }
}

The rendering of this page shows the text fields properly as I wanted, but the button has
white space on its left and right sides as it can be seen in the image below.

I tried multiple ways to add corner radius to it but couldn't succeed. Can anyone let me know how to fix this issue?

I think you just need to remove the horizontal padding on the blue rounded rectangle. Then, to hide the default row background, apply Color.clear as the list row background:
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(height: 50)
        // .padding(.horizontal, 20) //  HERE
    Button //...
}
.listRowBackground(Color.clear) //  AND HERE
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) // Remove default padding


Alternatively, you could move the styling to your own ButtonStyle:
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(.blue)
            }
    }
}

Form {
    Section(header: Text("Some Section")) {
        // ...
    }

    Button("Save your details") {
        saveDetails()
    }
    .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) // Remove default padding
}

The result looks the same, but this approach makes the styling more re-usable.
